# create function openerp 6.0

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-6

I created a module in openerp 6.0, the problem that openerp 6.0 did not support the same code as openerp 7, this is the function create: if some one can help me to solve the problem:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if vals['teacher_id']:
        teacher=self.pool.get("res.partner").browse(cr,uid,vals['teacher_id'],context)
        teacher.attendee=True
    if vals['etudiant_ids'][0][2]:
        for etudiant in self.pool.get("res.partner").browse(cr,uid,vals['etudiant_ids'][0][2],context):
            etudiant.attendee=True
    return super(attendee, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

the problem is in "if vals['etudiant_ids'][0][2]:"

```
if vals['etudiant_ids'][0][2]:
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Please use a codeblock and proper indentation, especially since the indentation is syntactically relevant in python. I tried to fix it, please check if it right.

Answer (score 1):

The above error comes, when you are accessing a dictionary, whose key is not found. 
The better way to debug is, use print statements to check the value
    print vals['etudiant_ids'],
    print vals['etudiant_ids'][0],
    print vals['etudiant_ids'][0][2],
and you can know where the key is not fetching.

and try to avoid ambigous statements, use vals.get('etudiant_ids') when using dictionaries, which will return False if the key not found instead of error.